# Name or service not known: AH00547: Could not resolve host name

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, vps, arch-linux

I get the `SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG` error message from Mozilla Firefox when connecting to my personal website:

```
Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to www.fturco.net. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
```

My website is hosted on a VPS server but I'm trying to access it from my personal computer at home.

This error message only happens immediately after I restart my VPS server. After boot if I restart `httpd.service` the problem vanishes.

These are the relevant messages from `/var/log/httpd/error_log`:

```
[Sat Sep 10 15:15:18.285512 2016] [core:error] [pid 228] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: AH00547: Could not resolve host name www.fturco.net -- ignoring!
[Sat Sep 10 15:15:18.289488 2016] [core:error] [pid 228] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: AH00547: Could not resolve host name tt-rss.fturco.net -- ignoring!
[Sat Sep 10 15:15:18.289571 2016] [core:error] [pid 228] (EAI 2)Name or service not known: AH00547: Could not resolve host name shaarli.fturco.net -- ignoring!
[Sat Sep 10 15:15:18.312224 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 228] AH00163: Apache/2.4.23 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/7.0.10 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Sep 10 15:15:18.312625 2016] [core:notice] [pid 228] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

This is my Apache configuration (`/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`):

```
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule php7_module modules/libphp7.so
LoadModule unixd_module modules/mod_unixd.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule mpm_prefork_module modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so

ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Listen 443
ServerAdmin fturco@fastmail.fm
ServerName fturco.net
DocumentRoot "/srv/http"

<IfModule dir_module>
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>

<IfModule unixd_module>
  User http
  Group http
</IfModule>

<Directory "/">
  AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory "/srv/http/">
  Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory ~ "/srv/http/shaarli/(application|cache|data|pagecache|tmp)/">
  Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory "/srv/http/tt-rss/cache/">
  Require all denied
</Directory>

ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/error_log"
LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
  TransferLog "/var/log/httpd/access_log"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
  TypesConfig conf/mime.types
  AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
</IfModule>

SSLCertificateFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/fturco.net/cert.pem"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/fturco.net/privkey.pem"
SSLCertificateChainFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/fturco.net/chain.pem"
SSLSessionCache "shmcb:/some/example/path/ssl_scache(512000)"

<VirtualHost www.fturco.net:443>
  ServerName www.fturco.net:443
  DocumentRoot "/srv/http/www"
  ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/www/error_log"
  TransferLog "/var/log/httpd/www/access_log"
  SSLEngine on
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost tt-rss.fturco.net:443>
  ServerName tt-rss.fturco.net:443
  DocumentRoot "/srv/http/tt-rss"
  ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/tt-rss/error_log"
  TransferLog "/var/log/httpd/tt-rss/access_log"
  SSLEngine on
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost shaarli.fturco.net:443>
  ServerName shaarli.fturco.net:443
  DocumentRoot "/srv/http/shaarli"
  ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/shaarli/error_log"
  TransferLog "/var/log/httpd/shaarli/access_log"
  SSLEngine on
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule headers_module>
  Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000"
</IfModule>

SSLProtocol All -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCompression off
SSLSessionTickets off
SSLUseStapling on
SSLStaplingResponderTimeout 5
SSLStaplingReturnResponderErrors off
SSLStaplingCache "shmcb:/var/run/ocsp(128000)"
```

This is my `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost vps
```

Command `hostname` returns `vps`.

My VPS server runs Arch Linux and `apache-2.4.23-1`.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems `VirtualHost` directives were wrong. The right way is:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName www.fturco.net
  DocumentRoot "/srv/http/www"
  ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/www/error_log"
  TransferLog "/var/log/httpd/www/access_log"
  SSLEngine on
</VirtualHost>
```

The only difference is in the first two lines.

Thanks to user BtbN from #httpd on Freenode.