apache SSL error after boot, but ok after systemctl restart
This is a weird one, I have a custom compiled apache 2.4 on an old CentOS 8 box, and I'm seeing odd behaviour at boot time.
I have a systemd service file :
[Unit]
Description=Apache 2.4 for Moodle
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
#Type=notify
ExecStart=/usr/local/apache/2.4/bin/apachectl start
ExecStop=/usr/local/apache/2.4/bin/apachectl stop
ExecReload=/usr/local/apache/2.4/bin/apachectl restart

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

and if I run systemctl start|restart moodleapache then it all behaves fine.
BUT
If I reboot the box, although httpd is clearly running (it's in the process table) I get a weird SSL error in a browser :
 Secure Connection Failed
 
An error occurred during a connection to blahblah.somewhere. SSL
received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
 
Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG
 
     The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
     Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.

Apache is running just fine :
 ps -ef | grep http
root        1087       1  0 13:15 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/apache/2.4/bin/httpd -k start
apache      1104    1087  0 13:15 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/apache/2.4/bin/httpd -k start
apache      1105    1087  0 13:15 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/apache/2.4/bin/httpd -k start
apache      1106    1087  0 13:15 ?        00:00:00 /usr/local/apache/2.4/bin/httpd -k start

and it's listening on 80 and 443 :
[carl@avmoodle ~]$ netstat -an | grep 80 | grep LIST
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
[carl@avmoodle ~]$ netstat -an | grep 443 | grep LIST
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN

Although interestingly, not on IPv4
I see the same after a systemctl restart moodleapache :
[root@avmoodle ~]# netstat -an | grep 80 | grep LIST
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
[root@avmoodle ~]# netstat -an | grep 443 | grep LIST
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN

Except, now the SSL error has gone away, and the website works just fine.
This has me a bit stumped. I can always start apache manually after a reboot, but something's not right.  SELinux is disabled, so it's not that :
avmoodle ~]# sestatus
SELinux status:                 disabled

um ... Any suggestions? Have I missed a dependancy in my .service file?
There's nothing interesting in the apache logs to tell me what's going on
@avmoodle logs]# more error_log
[Fri Dec 13 13:14:44.270580 2024] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 3942:tid 3942] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Dec 13 13:15:02.964278 2024] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1087:tid 1087] AH00489: Apache/2.4.62 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1k PHP/8.2.26 configured -
- resuming normal operations
[Fri Dec 13 13:15:02.988008 2024] [core:notice] [pid 1087:tid 1087] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/local/apache/2.4/bin/httpd'
[Fri Dec 13 13:20:26.006680 2024] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1087:tid 1087] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Fri Dec 13 13:20:26.092544 2024] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 4001:tid 4001] AH00489: Apache/2.4.62 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1k PHP/8.2.26 configured -
- resuming normal operations
[Fri Dec 13 13:20:26.092580 2024] [core:notice] [pid 4001:tid 4001] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/local/apache/2.4/bin/httpd'

and the other logs are empty.
I wonder if it's a urandom problem?  Some other timing issue?
Any suggestions?
Update:
    [root@avmoodle ~]# openssl s_client -connect localhost:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
140611185022784:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5 bytes and written 289 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---

[root@avmoodle ~]# systemctl restart moodleapache

[root@avmoodle ~]# openssl s_client -connect localhost:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
140688432351040:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5 bytes and written 289 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
[root@avmoodle ~]#

Once it's restarted, the site works as expected.
UPDATE :
after a lot of "WTF?"'ing, I fixed it. It turns out a VirtualHost config was wrong (why it worked in the first place and has for years I don't know!).
I recompiled Apache with mod_systemd support, enabled mod_systemd in the apache config, changed my service file to :
    avmoodle ~]# more /etc/systemd/system/moodleapache.service
[Unit]
Description=Apache 2.4 for Moodle
After=network.target

[Service]
#Type=forking
Type=notify
ExecStart=/usr/local/apache/2.4/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND -k start
ExecReload=/usr/local/apache/2.4/bin/httpd -k graceful
KillMode=mixed
#ExecStart=/usr/local/apache/2.4/bin/apachectl start
#ExecStop=/usr/local/apache/2.4/bin/apachectl stop
#ExecReload=/usr/local/apache/2.4/bin/apachectl restart

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

and ran into this error :
Name or service not known: AH00547

Searching that error found this :
https://serverfault.com/questions/802287/name-or-service-not-known-ah00547-could-not-resolve-host-name

And lo!  It was an error in my VirtualHost setup.
"fixed"

inspecting the certificate before you restart the service could shed some light. The apache config itself could also be relevant.

CentOS 8 has been EOL for quite some time now, you really should upgrade to a supported release.

If it starts with a systemctl restart, then the certificate must be ok.

openssl s_client -connect localhost:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
139853532079936:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:
no peer certificate available
No client certificate CA names sent
SSL handshake has read 5 bytes and written 289 bytes
Verification: OK
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
--- Note that this is the same after a systemctl restart (as I'd expect)

Please don't post any additional information into comments, they are unreadable here. Instead, edit your question.
